# Best data source method with multiple applications running

Tags: excel, vb.net, ms-access

I currently have an application that takes an entered part number, searches for a folder named that entered number, opens an excel file named that entered number, reads some stuff and then closes the excel file. This application is currently running on 8 lines at the same time and there are currently 241 part numbers any of them can run. This app updates by redoing that process every 30 mins. The issue is that if i have to edit or add any information for the app to pull I have to do that 241 times.

I have been thinking about about putting all this data in an excel or access file so all i have to do is add a new column instead of opening up 241 excel files. But im worried about what would i do when 8 or all 35 lines in the shop are pulling from the same file, possibly at the same time. Ps I do have an sql link for some of the data.

Any suggestions or recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Having multiple sources of data that are difficult/risky to edit is an accident waiting to happen.  Why not have a single central database (Access can do the trick, SQL Server would be better) that the applications all use?  Keep one record of the data in one place.  Push out updates to the database and applications as part of a mostly (or fully) automated deployment.

Comment: What if 1.) Im adding content to the database when an app tries to open and pull 2.) What if 2 apps try at the same time?

Comment: Databases are designed to handle exactly those situations.  *Files* are not.

Comment: Ok, I have no experience with databases. Is an access file a database?

Comment: It's a kind of database, yes.  You wouldn't so much "open the file" as you would connect to the database by means of a connection string, which uses a database driver installed on the machine.  For small applications, MS Access can certainly do the job.  But I'd recommend going with something more robust sooner rather than later.  I believe there's a free edition of SQL Server.  There are also things like MySQL.

Comment: The issue i see with that is my company would not allow that and i do not have admin rights to install stuff. All the computers on the shop floor are linked to a network.

Comment: Improving the application design is going to prove difficult if you're not permitted to change the application design.

Comment: Thats what im worried about... I could put in a request but i dont know enough about databases i feel to set up a SQL. You said access could do it, can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: If all the data is in an Excel or text file and all clients are only accessing it using "read-only" mode then there should be no problem.  Managing updates would mean you just overwrite the file with a new version (do not open the same file everyone else is reading from: edit a separate copy and then do a replace).